# Searching properties in neo4j queries

Tags: neo4j, cypher

There is a node Person which consists of 2 properties : firstName, lastName . The user may input firstName or lastName or both. If both names are specified there is no guarantee that the names are in firstName and lastName order . For example : if a name is `sherlock holmes` , the user may give `holmes sherlock` or only `sherlock` or `holmes` or `sherlock holmes`. In all these cases we must get the sherlock holmes node. If no input is specified then all the Person nodes are to be returned.

I tried the following query :

```
Match (n : Person )
where n.firstName+" "+n.lastName ={1} or n.lastName+" "+n.firstName={1}  
return n
```

Where {1} is the name.

Can anyone help me out !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATED twice]

Something like the following should work.

```
WITH SPLIT($name, ' ') AS parts
WITH parts, SIZE(parts)=1 AS one_part
MATCH (n: Person)
WHERE
  parts IS NULL OR
  (n.firstName=parts[0] AND (one_part OR n.lastName=parts[1])) OR
  (n.lastName=parts[0] AND (one_part OR n.firstName=parts[1])) OR
  (parts[0] = '' AND NOT EXISTS(n.firstName) AND NOT EXISTS(n.lastName))
RETURN n
```

Special cases:

- If the `name` parameter is NULL, then all `Person` nodes are returned.
- If the `name` parameter is an empty string, then this query will match any `Person` node having an empty string as the `firstName` or `lastName` value, or having neither of those properties.

Comment: Thanks for the query. The query worked only if some name input is given, else it did not return any nodes. Can you help with that case too...

Comment: What nodes do you expect the query to return if no `$name` is specified?

Comment: I have updated my answer to support the special case of the `name` parameter having an empty string value. Does that help? A query that uses a parameter must be passed a value for that parameter -- you cannot just omit it.

Comment: The name may or may not be passed. If not passed all the nodes must be returned.

Comment: The `name` parameter must be passed, or you'd get an error. I assume you mean that you can pass `null`? See my updated answer.

Comment: By the way: all relevant details (like the ones in these comments) should have been included in your question, so that the correct answer could be presented immediately.